# List<T> to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dictionary

I have a `List<CustomObject>`
which has 3 properties
A,B,C
and what I need is to transform this List to a Dictionary so the result looks like

```
Dictionary<string,object>
(Property name) A = Value of A
(Property name) B = Value of B
(Property name) C = Value of C
```

Pls suggest...

Comment: I would make it `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: yeah no problem with that...I am looking for a sloution

Comment: IIRC I posted the solution (using Reflection.Emit) for this in another question. It was long ago, and I cant recall the link now. Will post if I find it.

Comment: Uhm, you have a strange notation, what should the key for the dictionary be, and what should the value be?

Comment: Erm, how is this dictionary only ever going to have more than 3 entries?

Comment: Should the result be a list of dictionaries or what?

Comment: As all the property names are different, it should be just one dictionary

Comment: @Hans Passant: Who says there arent derived types with many extra properties?

Comment: This dictionary is just going to have 3 entries and all keys are unique

Comment: Could you just say: Dictionary<string, object> StringToObject = new Dictionary<string, object>(); StringToObject["PropertyA"] = A; StringToObject["PropertyB"] = B; ...etc.  I suspect you may be confusing your terms though, List<CustomObject> can't have properties (that you define), it has members (that you define-of type CustomObject).

Comment: @chugh97: Found it :) It is exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CustomObject instance = new CustomObject();
var dict = instance.GetType().GetProperties()
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(instance, null));
```

Comment: You need `instance.GetType()` to make it work on any type, else quite a nice 'one liner'  :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the code :)  Originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594527/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-properties-of-an-anonymous-object-in-c/2594545#2594545).

```
static T CreateDelegate<T>(this DynamicMethod dm) where T : class
{
  return dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(T)) as T;
}

static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>>> cache = 
   new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>>>();

static Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties(object o)
{
  var t = o.GetType();

  Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>> getter;

  if (!cache.TryGetValue(t, out getter))
  {
    var rettype = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>);

    var dm = new DynamicMethod(t.Name + ":GetProperties", rettype, 
       new Type[] { typeof(object) }, t);

    var ilgen = dm.GetILGenerator();

    var instance = ilgen.DeclareLocal(t);
    var dict = ilgen.DeclareLocal(rettype);

    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, t);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, instance);

    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, rettype.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, dict);

    var add = rettype.GetMethod("Add");

    foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties(
      BindingFlags.Instance |
      BindingFlags.Public))
    {
      ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, dict);

      ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, prop.Name);

      ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, instance);
      ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, prop);
      ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(object));

      ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, add);
    }

    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, dict);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    cache[t] = getter = 
      dm.CreateDelegate<Func<object, Dictionary<string, object>>>();
  }

  return getter(o);
}
```

For given type:

```
class Foo
{
  public string A {get;}
  public int B {get;}
  public bool C {get;}
}
```

It produces a delegate equivalent to:

```
(Foo f) => new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    { "A", f.A },
    { "B", f.B },
    { "C", f.C },
  };
```

**Disclaimer:** Looking at the code now (without testing) there may need to be special handling for valuetypes (instead of just the castclass). Exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Hath: I was 'forced' to write it for a translation/globalization system to had to reflect fast over WinForm controls.  :)

Comment: awesome! I was just starting to code it this way, but You have managed to do it faster:)THat definately the fastest possible method of doing it:) Although probably not that elegant like a LINQ one:)

Comment: @luckyluke: A thumbsucking estimate would be at least 20 times faster. Nothing is as elegant as LINQ.  But you know, in Scheme you could simply write a macro to do this and have it just as fast :)  (as long as the type is known at compile time)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you have to use reflrecion on CustomObject to get the property names then simply create the dictionary:

dic.add(propertyName, value);

Comment: Very boring and very slow  :)