# Linq group by except column

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a class with large amount of properties that I need to group by almost all columns.

```
class Sample {
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
    public string S4 { get; set; }
    // ... all the way to this:
    public string S99 { get; set; }

    public decimal? N1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? N2 { get; set; }
    public decimal? N3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? N4 { get; set; }
    // ... all the way to this:
    public decimal? N99 { get; set; }
}
```

From time to time I need to group by all columns except one or two decimal columns and return some result based on this (namely object with all the fields, but with some decimal value as a sum or max).

Is there are any extension method that would allow me to do something like this:

```
sampleCollection.GroupByExcept(x => x.N2, x => x.N5).Select(....);
```

instead of specifying all columns in object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find anything builtin that handles such a case. You'd have to create one yourself. Depending on how robust you need this to be, you could take a number of approaches.

The main hurdle you'll come across is how you'll generate the key type. In an ideal situation, the new keys that are generated would have their own distinct type. But it would have to be dynamically generated.

Alternatively, you could use another type that could hold multiple distinct values and still could be suitably used as the key. Problem here is that it will still have to be dynamically generated, but you will be using existing types.

A different approach you could take that doesn't involve generating new types, would be to use the existing source type, but reset the excluded properties to their default values (or not set them at all). Then they would have no effect on the grouping. This assumes you can create instances of this type and modify its values.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TSource, TSource>> GroupByExcept<TSource, TXKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TXKey>> exceptKeySelector) =>
        GroupByExcept(source, exceptKeySelector, s => s);

    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TSource, TElement>> GroupByExcept<TSource, TXKey, TElement>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TXKey>> exceptKeySelector, Expression<Func<TSource, TElement>> elementSelector)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(BuildKeySelector(), elementSelector);

        Expression<Func<TSource, TSource>> BuildKeySelector()
        {
            var exclude = typeof(TXKey).GetProperties()
                .Select(p => (p.PropertyType, p.Name))
                .ToHashSet();
            var itemExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
            var keyExpr = Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(typeof(TSource).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)),
                from p in typeof(TSource).GetProperties()
                where !exclude.Contains((p.PropertyType, p.Name))
                select Expression.Bind(p, Expression.Property(itemExpr, p))
            );
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TSource>>(keyExpr, itemExpr);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it you would do this:

```
sampleCollection.GroupByExcept(x => new { x.N2, x.N5 })...
```

But alas, this approach won't work under normal circumstances. You won't be able to create new instances of the type within a query (unless you're using Linq to Objects).

---

If you're using Roslyn, you could generate that type as needed, then use that object as your key. Though that'll mean you'll need to generate the type asynchronously. So you probably will want to separate this from your query all together and just generate the key selector.

```
public static async Task<Expression<Func<TSource, object>>> BuildExceptKeySelectorAsync<TSource, TXKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TXKey>> exceptKeySelector)
{
    var exclude = typeof(TXKey).GetProperties()
        .Select(p => (p.PropertyType, p.Name))
        .ToHashSet();
    var properties =
        (from p in typeof(TSource).GetProperties()
        where !exclude.Contains((p.PropertyType, p.Name))
        select p).ToList();
    var targetType = await CreateTypeWithPropertiesAsync(
        properties.Select(p => (p.PropertyType, p.Name))
    );
    var itemExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var keyExpr = Expression.New(
        targetType.GetConstructors().Single(),
        properties.Select(p => Expression.Property(itemExpr, p)),
        targetType.GetProperties()
    );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(keyExpr, itemExpr);

    async Task<Type> CreateTypeWithPropertiesAsync(IEnumerable<(Type type, string name)> properties) =>
        (await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<object>(
            AnonymousObjectCreationExpression(
                SeparatedList(
                    properties.Select(p =>
                        AnonymousObjectMemberDeclarator(
                            NameEquals(p.name),
                            DefaultExpression(ParseTypeName(p.type.FullName))
                        )
                    )
                )
            ).ToFullString()
        )).GetType();
}
```

To use this:

```
sampleCollection.GroupBy(
    await BuildExceptKeySelector((CollectionType x) => new { x.N2, x.N5 })
).Select(....);
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from this answer [here:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e68c5ac-fd9e-46e8-9192-7e9dcd0cb598/c-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns?forum=csharpgeneral)

Create a class `EqualityComparer`

```
public class EqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> xP = x as IDictionary<string, object>;
        IDictionary<string, object> yP = y as IDictionary<string, object>;

        if (xP.Count != yP.Count)
            return false;
        if (xP.Keys.Except(yP.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        if (yP.Keys.Except(xP.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        foreach (var pair in xP)
            if (pair.Value.Equals( yP[pair.Key])==false)
                return false;
        return true;

    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then create your `GroupContent` method:

```
private void GroupContent<T>(List<T> dataList, string[] columns, string[] columnsToExclude)
    {
string[] columnsToGroup = columns.Except(columnsToExclude).ToArray();
        EqualityComparer<IDictionary<string, object>> equalityComparer = new EqualityComparer<IDictionary<string, object>>();
        var groupedList = dataList.GroupBy(x =>
        {
            var groupByColumns = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)groupByColumns).Clear();
            foreach (string column in columnsToGroup)
                ((IDictionary<string, object>)groupByColumns).Add(column, GetPropertyValue(x, column));
            return groupByColumns;
        }, equalityComparer);


        foreach (var item in groupedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group : " + string.Join(",", item.Key));
            foreach (object obj in item)
                Console.WriteLine("Item : " + obj);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended the code above borrowing another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10241909/9664733).

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<T> GroupBye<T, C>(this IEnumerable<T> query, Func<IGrouping<IDictionary<string, object>, T>, C> grouping) where T : class
    {
        var cProps = typeof(C).GetProperties().Select(prop => prop.Name).ToArray();
        var columnsToGroup = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(prop => prop.Name).Except(cProps).ToArray();
        var equalityComparer = new EqualityComparer<IDictionary<string, object>>();
        return query
            .GroupBy(x => ExpandoGroupBy(x, columnsToGroup), equalityComparer)
            .Select(x => MergeIntoNew(x, grouping, cProps));
    }

    private static IDictionary<string, object> ExpandoGroupBy<T>(T x, string[] columnsToGroup) where T : class
    {
        var groupByColumns = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
        groupByColumns.Clear();
        foreach (string column in columnsToGroup)
            groupByColumns.Add(column, typeof(T).GetProperty(column).GetValue(x, null));
        return groupByColumns;
    }

    private static T MergeIntoNew<T, C>(IGrouping<IDictionary<string, object>, T> x, Func<IGrouping<IDictionary<string, object>, T>, C> grouping, string[] cProps) where T : class
    {
        var tCtor = typeof(T).GetConstructors().Single();
        var tCtorParams = tCtor.GetParameters().Select(param => param.Name).ToArray();
        //Calling grouping lambda function
        var grouped = grouping(x);
        var paramsValues = tCtorParams.Select(p => cProps.Contains(p) ? typeof(C).GetProperty(p).GetValue(grouped, null) : x.Key[p]).ToArray();
        return (T)tCtor.Invoke(paramsValues);
    }

    private class EqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            var xDict = x as IDictionary<string, object>;
            var yDict = y as IDictionary<string, object>;

            if (xDict.Count != yDict.Count)
                return false;
            if (xDict.Keys.Except(yDict.Keys).Any())
                return false;
            if (yDict.Keys.Except(xDict.Keys).Any())
                return false;
            foreach (var pair in xDict)
                if (pair.Value == null && yDict[pair.Key] == null)
                    continue;
                else if (pair.Value == null || !pair.Value.Equals(yDict[pair.Key]))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return obj.ToString().GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be used in the following way:

```
var list = enumerable.GroupBye(grp => new
    {
        Value = grp.Sum(val => val.Value)
    });
```

The result will like grouping all other columns but Value, which will be valued to the sum of grouped elements' value