# JSON to ExpandoObject convertion in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, expandoobject

```
{  
"Jhone":[  
  {  
     "Key":"Employeename",
     "Value":"Jhone"
  },
  {  
     "Key":"Address",
     "Value":[  
        {  
           "Key":"City",
           "Value":"Newyork"
        },
        {  
           "Key":"Country",
           "Value":"USA"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"Mohamed":[  
  {  
     "Key":"Employeename",
     "Value":"Mohamed"
  },
  {  
     "Key":"Address",
     "Value":[  
        {  
           "Key":"City",
           "Value":"Delhi"
        },
        {  
           "Key":"Country",
           "Value":"india"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

This is my JSON format. How to convert in to ExpandoObject in c#?
Here is my code as

```
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var ictionarys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(value);
foreach (var item in ictionarys)
{
List<object> itemList = new List<object>();

foreach (var item2 in (ICollection)item.Value)
{
   //Here how to code
}                   
Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "=> " + item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Could you give more information about why you specifically want `ExpandoObject`? If you just want a dynamic way of accessing the JSON, have you tried just using `JObject`? (`dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(value);` and then work from there...)

Comment: Json.NET supports deserializing to `ExpandoObject` directly, as mentioned in https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dynamic.  Have you tried it?  See e.g. [Deserialize Dynamic Json string using Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22906010/3744182)

Comment: @Daisy Shipton, Thank you. But when we Address Key, That value is as Json. How to change inner JObject.parse(value)

Comment: `var expando = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(value);` just works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZEPkye for a demo.  What is your problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean in your comment. Yes, you'd need to find the object that has a "Key" property with a value of "Address", due to the way your JSON is structured... you could easily create a `Dictionary<string, JObject>` if that's more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this extension method

```
public static ExpandoObject Expando(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> dictionary)
{
    var expando = new ExpandoObject();
    var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
    foreach (var item in dictionary)
    {
        expandoDic.Add(item);
    }
    return expando;
}
```

Method return ExpandoObject with key,value list

Comment: Thank you. But We want as dictionary<name,expandoObejct> like
dictionary<Mohamed,ExpandoObject>,dictionary<Jhon,ExpandoOject> Like this

Comment: On your code, The value of the dictionary as Json value, we want as expandoObject?