# Json.NET: Parsing object array of unknown length

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSON array that looks something like this:

```
{
  "chatName": "Test",
  "users": [
    "User1",
    "User2"
  ],
  "someBooleanValue": true,
  "someObjects": {
    "object1": "someObjectValue1",
    "object2": "someObjectValue2",
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to parse the someObjects array of objects, when I don't know how many objects the array will have before I start processing the JSON file?

All the parsing is done using Json.NET.

Comment: someObjects looks like an object with properties, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` for someObjects. Code can look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RootObject
{
    public string chatName { get; set; }
    public List<string> users { get; set; }
    public bool someBooleanValue { get; set; }
    public dynamic someObjects { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        string j = "{\"chatName\": \"Test\",\"users\": [\"User1\",\"User2\"],\"someBooleanValue\": true,\"someObjects\": {\"object1\": \"someObjectValue1\",\"object2\": \"someObjectValue2\"}}";

        RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(j);

        Console.WriteLine(ro.someObjects.object1);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through someObject's properties and get it's value (such as someObjectValue1), since I don't know the name of each individual property (object1 and object2 names change often).

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594527/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-properties-of-an-anonymous-object-in-c

Answer (score 0):

`someObjects` needs to be deserailized either to an `Object` (class) or a `JObject` (C# json) or to some kind of `Dictionary`.

You can Deserialize the json using json.net's method:
 `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize
Converts an object to a JSON string.

string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(object name);

similarly to deserialize  you can use  Deserialize function

string json = "{\"chatName\": \"Test\",\"users\": [\"User1\",\"User2\"],\"someBooleanValue\": true,\"someObjects\": {\"object1\": \"someObjectValue1\",\"object2\": \"someObjectValue2\"}}";

Classname objectname = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(json);

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is very bad choice.